# MultiWriter in Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: multiwriter

I am running Kubuntu 19.04 and trying to create a live USB using MultiWriter.  When I launch the program it activates, but then shuts down immediately without explanation.  I've tried to run it from the command line, but can't find the program.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is Multiwriter?

Comment: A program to write files such as isos to usb drives, in some cases multiple times.